# How to create a multi line chart from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a csv file with 3 columns:

1. Timestamp
2. Measured response time
3. Model name

```
Timestamp,ResponseTime,Model
16-07-2021 17:59:22,1.421802,trained_sm_95
16-07-2021 17:59:23,1.414357,trained_sm_95
16-07-2021 17:59:25,1.623063,trained_sm_95
16-07-2021 17:59:27,1.401964,trained_md_96
16-07-2021 17:59:28,1.4,trained_md_96
16-07-2021 17:59:29,1.396638,trained_md_96
16-07-2021 17:59:31,1.601539,trained_lg_95
16-07-2021 17:59:33,1.205376,trained_lg_95
16-07-2021 17:59:34,1.411902,trained_lg_95
```

I want to visualize the response time in a multiple line chart with 3 lines, one for each model.
My code looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\times.csv')
#pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'],errors='ignore') 
sm = df.ResponseTime[df["Model"] == 'trained_sm_95']
md = df.ResponseTime[df["Model"] == 'trained_md_96']
lg = df.ResponseTime[df["Model"] == 'trained_lg_95']

x = df.Timestamp
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"
plt.scatter(x, y)

plt.plot( 'x', 'sm', data=df)
plt.plot( 'x', 'md', data=df)
plt.plot( 'x', 'lg', data=df)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The code is currently breaking at this line:

```py
plt.plot('x', 'lg', data=df)
```

with this error:

> ValueError: Unrecognized character `l` in format string

I don't see what's wrong with the code.

How can I load and visualize the data as described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there are multiple mistakes here... first, to plot your data, you have to pass the variables into the function parameters, whereas you are passing strings that are the same as the variable names... so it should look like this.

```
plt.plot(x, sm)
plt.plot(x, md)
plt.plot(x, lg)
```

Your syntax would be valid only if *df* **would** contain 'x', 'lg', 'md' or 'sm', which could be accessed through eg.

```
df['x']
```

If it does, then, and only then, you could use the syntax you were using. Look here for more detail [Plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) Don't be afraid to read the docs :)

Comment: thanks for the quick response. 
I adapted it now like this to make it working:

plt.plot( df.Timestamp[df["Model"] == 'trained_sm_95'], df.ResponseTime[df["Model"] == 'trained_sm_95'])
plt.plot( df.Timestamp[df["Model"] == 'trained_md_96'], df.ResponseTime[df["Model"] == 'trained_md_96'])
plt.plot( df.Timestamp[df["Model"] == 'trained_lg_95'], df.ResponseTime[df["Model"] == 'trained_lg_95'])